# Is it possible to change the column and record delimiter in sqoop2?

Tags: apache, sqoop

Is it possbile to change the default column delimiter (comma) to a different character in Sqoop2?  I read in some mail archives that it is not supported yet.

If no, how can we specify the enclosed-by and escaped-by chars so that Sqoop properly extracts columns with values containing comma and quotes?  Does this work by default or need to turn it on by setting any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I doubted, changing the delimiter is not yet supported in Sqoop2. Refer below:

http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/137q954ffz/sqoop2-import-field-delimiter

- By default, the column delimiter is comma
- String fields should be enclosed within single quotes (this takes care of fields with comma in them)
- If the field contains single quote in itself then escape it with backslash \